# How do i change language in Joomla's Nano template Mobile

Tags: php, templates, mobile, joomla2.5

I have made a site in Joomla. With the template [Nano](http://yootheme.com/demo/). There was a mobile template as well, which I'm using. (I'm not using Joomla mobile). well.. i have made my site now, and there is a button in the bottom of the site, where i can swap to the desktop version. This is written in English "Switch to desktop version". i want this in danish. Where can i chance this? I have been looking in every php. doc, ini files etc. Can't find it :(
I have chanced the language in Joomla, and it is working fin on the desktop website.
Any suggestion how to solve this?

If you got a mobile you can visit the site [here](http://martinehlers.dk)

Answer (score 0):

If it is in a language file, then your best bet is to use the built in Joomla language overrides to find it. In the admin -

1. In the Extensions menu, click on Language Manager
2. Click the Overrides link
3. Click the new Override button
4. In the search form that appears search for "Switch to desktop version" with Value selected.
5. If it finds the value in a language file, just click the result and edit in what ever you want.

If it does not find it in a language file, then you will have to look through the template files, it has been hard coded directly in somewhere.